# Microsoft.Expression.Controls Callout pointanchor to a control

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to set the PointAnchor of a Callout control `Microsoft.Expression.Controls` to a WPF Control ,

i've tried something like

```
public static void PointMe(this Callout me,UIElement ui)
{
         Me.AnchorPoint = ????? // don't know how to get the ui coordinates
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Based on the OP's re-explanation that the desired result is to move the AnchorPoint and not the entire Callout, I'm adding another answer so that my first answer can be left for other's use if needed since it moves the Callout.

---

There doesn't seem to be any built-in framework method to move a Callout's AnchorPoint relative to another element on the screen.

The AnchorPoint of a Callout is based on the *Relative Position* of the Callout's top and left corner. You can move the AnchorPoint by calculating the distance between the Callout and any other element and then do a bit of math to come up with the relative positioning. The following *should* work:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="so.ExpCallout.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
        Title="Callout Anchor Point"
        Width="625"
        Height="350"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ed:Callout x:Name="MyCallout"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="100"
                    Margin="200,50,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AnchorPoint="0,1.5"
                    CalloutStyle="Rectangle"
                    Content="Callout"
                    Stroke="Black" />

        <Button x:Name="LeftButton"
                Width="100"
                Height="25"
                Margin="50,200,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="OnLeftButtonClick"
                Content="Left" />

        <Button x:Name="RightButton"
                Width="100"
                Height="25"
                Margin="450,200,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="OnRightButtonClick"
                Content="Right" />

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace so.ExpCallout
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnRightButtonClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            AdjustCalloutAnchor( RightButton );
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void OnLeftButtonClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            AdjustCalloutAnchor( LeftButton );
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void AdjustCalloutAnchor( FrameworkElement el )
        {
            // locate the positions of the callout and the element to point to
            Point calloutPoint = MyCallout.TransformToAncestor( LayoutRoot ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
            Point elementPoint = el.TransformToAncestor( LayoutRoot ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );

            double vertOffset = calloutPoint.Y + MyCallout.ActualHeight;
            double horizOffset = elementPoint.X;
            if( calloutPoint.X > elementPoint.X )
            {
                // increase the horizontal offset if the callout 
                // is to the right of the element
                horizOffset += el.ActualWidth;
            }

            double vertDistance = ( elementPoint.Y + el.ActualHeight ) - vertOffset;
            double horizDistance = calloutPoint.X - horizOffset;

            // add some cushion between the element and the new AnchorPoint
            int pad = 5;

            // the AnchorPoint is a relative distance based on the actual height
            // and width of the callout.
            double x = ( horizDistance / ( MyCallout.ActualWidth + pad ) ) * -1;
            double y = ( vertDistance / ( MyCallout.ActualHeight + pad ) ) + 1;

            // set the new AnchorPoint location
            MyCallout.AnchorPoint = new Point( x, y );

            MyCallout.Content = string.Format( "I'm pointing at {0}", el.Name );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to make some minor adjustments to the padding based on your scenario. Hopefully it works out for you. And it was a fun exercise as well.

Comment: After seeing your code, I know what AnchorPoint Property Means, its relative to the Width & Height of the callout, so I'll make a lot of adjustments, even I'll create a UserControl for that, thank you again !!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways this could be accomplished. One would be to place everything in a `Canvas` and move the `Callout` based on the x/y canvas coordinates of the control you want to position the callout next to.

A more flexible method would be to use the [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to locate where the control you want to anchor the callout to is positioned, relative to some ancestor element. In this case, the best element to position against is the root element.

Here is a working example:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ed:Callout x:Name="MyCallout"
                Width="200"
                Height="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                AnchorPoint="0,1.5"
                CalloutStyle="Rectangle"
                Content="Callout"
                Stroke="Black" />

    <Button x:Name="LeftButton"
            Width="75"
            Margin="100,0,0,150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="OnLeftButtonClick"
            Content="Left" />

    <Button x:Name="RightButton"
            Width="75"
            Margin="300,0,0,150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="OnRightButtonClick"
            Content="Right" />

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void OnLeftButtonClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    MoveCallout( LeftButton );
    e.Handled = true;
}


private void OnRightButtonClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    MoveCallout( RightButton );
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void MoveCallout( FrameworkElement element )
{
    // find the position of the element to anchor against relative to the root object
    Point point = element.TransformToAncestor( LayoutRoot ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );

    // take into account the width of the anchor element
    double x = point.X + element.ActualWidth;

    // take into account the height of the anchor element and the callout
    // add a little wiggle room as well
    double y = point.Y - element.ActualHeight - MyCallout.ActualHeight - 10;

    MyCallout.Content = element.Name;

    // Move the callout to the new coordinates
    MyCallout.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform( x, y );
}
```

Comment: But I want the **AnchorPoint** to be positioned to the control not moving (translating) the entire callout, because my Callout has a fixed position

Comment: In essence, you want the AnchorPoint to stretch to the location of the button. If that's the case, the above is close, but instead of moving the entire Callout, you'd need to calculate the relative position of the AnchorPoint as related to the Callout itself and the distance from the right edge of the button. If I have time, I'll see what I can come up with; no promises, though.

Comment: I've tried to calculate that, but the couldn't relate the anchorpoint with the control nor with the callout, That would be a real real help, take your time, & thank u in advance !